# Set volume for notification without set the ringtone volume

Tags: android, notifications

I want to manage the volume of all system notifications.

If I use this the call volume is changed too.

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, 0);
```

How can I change only the notifications volume?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the notification sound using **Notification** class. i.e

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setContentText(message);

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/generic");
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```